# Linear Algebra, Finding Eigenvector Basis (in Matlab?)

Tags: linear-algebra

"Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ random matrix and let $B = A^TA$ (note that the entries
of the matrix $B$ are symmetric with respect to the diagonal. Such a matrix is called a
symmetric matrix). Find a basis of eigenvectors for the matrix $B$, and check that this basis
is orthogonal."

Does anyone know how to do this, especially in Matlab? I am only really familiar with how to find eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Given some `A`, there are two ways to find the eigenvectors of `B=A'*A`:

1. `[V, D] = eig(A'*A)` and `V` is the required matrix of eigenvectors.
2. (better!) `[U, S, V] = svd(A)` and `U` is the required matrix of eigenvectors.

Comment: So the basis is just the evects themselves? How do I check they are orthonormal in Matlab?

Comment: You know the usual $\mathbf Q^\top\mathbf Q=\mathbf I$ condition, no?

Comment: Can Q be formed from the eigenvectors in any convenient manner?

Is Q just each column divided by its length?

Comment: Orthogonal* sorry

Comment: `V` in the first, and `U` in the second, are what you perform the `Q'*Q` operation on...

Comment: The just proved the dot products between some entries were all zero. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you did get something resembling the result of `eye()`, no?